# Should I delete rows or take average of it?

Tags: mean

So I got 2 data files. First one is energy intake (in watts) for every minute in a household and the other contains the average temperature in the house for every 5 minutes.

Each file is from the same date in year 2017.

Here is an example:

**Power Consumption in Watts per Minute**

[image: Power Consumption in Watts per Minute]

**Average House Temperature per 5 Minutes**

[image: Average House Temperature per 5 Minutes]

So as you can see, the two dataset are different in their respective times. My goal is store these two data sets into a database, so my question is should I just edit the **power consumption** data so that it is the same with the **temperature** data (by only taking the average of every 5 minutes and deleting the any other minutes), then merge the two dataset together and dump it into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you are thinking is probably fine. But there is one downside: it would hide occasions when there is a big temporary spike in powetur consumption.

The alternative approach would be to interpolate the temperatures, to estimate a temperature every minute.